# From which book is the backstory of Yennefer taken?

Tags: character, book-adaptation, the-witcher

In the games of *The Witcher* series *Yennefer* meets *Geralt of Rivia* for curing *Dandelion* who was harmed by the Jinn, but in the *Netflix* series we see a proper back story of *Yennefer* and her childhood and origin is shown. Which book of the series is taken as a reference to tell the backstory or have the writers of the series created that from their own?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yennefer's backstory is aluded to in *The Tower of Swallows*:

> Janka! Dear Janka!
>
> Take this hunchbacked monstrosity from me! I don’t want to look at it!
>
> She’s your daughter as much as she is mine.
>
> Indeed? The children I have sired are normal.
>
> How dare you… How dare you suggest…
>
> It was in your elven family that there were witches. It was you that aborted your first pregnancy. It was because of that. You have tainted elven blood and a tainted womb, woman. That’s why you give birth to monsters.
>
> It is an ill-fated child… Such was the will of the gods! She’s your daughter as much as she is mine! What was I to do? Smother her? Not tie the birth cord? What am I to do now? Take her to the forest and leave her? What do you want from me, by the Gods?
>
> Daddy! Mummy!
>
> Get away, you freak.
>
> How dare you! How dare you strike a child! Stop! Where are you going? Where? To her, are you? To her!
>
> Yes, woman. I’m a man. I’m free to sate my lust where and when I want, as is my natural right. And I loathe you. You and the fruit of your degenerate womb. Don’t wait with supper. I won’t be back tonight.
>
> Mummy…
>
> Why are you weeping?
>
> Why are you beating me and pushing me away? I was good, wasn’t I?
>
> - Chapter 9, [The Tower of The Swallow](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Tower_of_the_Swallow.html?id=8zN_CgAAQBAJ&q=%22Janka!%20Dear%20Janka!%22)

And Geralt, after meeting Yennefer in *The Last Wish* and wondering what her former deformity must have been (most candidates for sorceresses having been 'unmarriagable' young women), discovers:

> He knew what she used to be. What she remembered, what she couldn't forget, what she lived with. Who she really was before she had become a sorceress. Her cold, penetrating, angry and wise eyes were those of a hunchback.

Yennefer alludes to this in *Blood of Elves*:

> Can I, through magic, be as pretty as you one day?”
>
> “You… Fortunately you don’t have to… You don’t need magic for it. You don’t know how lucky you are.”